# Curl and wget returning 404 on hosted server , works fine from outside

Tags: apache, .htaccess, curl, centos

I am trying to do a simple curl command from from my hosted server and it returns 404 , but when i run the same command form my own machine or browser it works fine .

The weird part is i am running two websites on same server and the second website is working fine by using curl on the server or from my machine . But this one has the issue where it will work for index page , but any other page will returns 404 .

I have checked out htacess and also logs , nothing helpfull .

I looked at many other posts and google but could not find a working answer .Appreciate your help .

I am using Cent Os 4 .

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out if the machine knows locally about its dns entry.

So, your DNS server, that you are using at home knows that the server coded in the url is that particular server. And the outward router of the hoster obviously knows that. But that does not mean that the machine itself know that too.

So just try a

```
nslookup www.yourdomain.com
```

from the shell at the hosted server and see if it knows its identity.

If not you could enter your domain as a additonal entry for 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file.

Domain name resolution always use the hosts file first, then the configured dns server(s) - and then fail.

Comment: Hey kei , i did nslookup and it is showing me the server address and the njon authoritive answer with the Ip and the domain name . So i am assuming that my machine knows about its DNS entry .

Comment: Is the ip adress that you see there the internet ip or the inside net ip of the hosted server? If it is the WAN (internet) ip this means that the request would have to go form the inside of the server over the internet to the outside address -> the the hoster's router etc. Maybe the just block that. It should however work if you add an entry of the servers internal ip or 127.0.0.1 in hosts and connect that domain.

Comment: Well here it how it looks ,nslookup www.bizmanualz.com
Server:         some ip ( i cannot go to this Ip from outside)
Address:        some ip #53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.bizmanualz.com
Address: 72.52.220.243 - external ip

Comment: Hmm on the other hand, it give you a 404 not a host not found. So the dns thing is probably not the reason.

Comment: Yes it only shows 404 when i try to go to http://www.bizmanualz.com/blog or anywhere in directory except homepage  . It finds the home page perfectly . And this only happens when i am doing from server itself , if u try to do it u will get 200 ok .

Comment: So the last thing that is open, is that here is something funny in the apache config.

Comment: I dont know , i removed my whole htacess to check if it works and no issue , and i have checked httpd.conf , but havent seen anything tricky  .But not sure , any sugeestional changes in httpd.conf  and yes i have cpanel installed .

Comment: Is /blog/ a reverse proxied other server?

Comment: Let me rephrase: Is all the site wordpress, or is the blog a wordpress blog that is "injected" into the url scheme via reverse proxy?

Comment: I dont think so , but i would have to confirm that with my host provider

Comment: If the blog is inserted into the url via reverse proxy, then you would really have to check the directives in the http.conf. Proxying does some magic which might cause something like that. But that would mean, that all requests to some part of the site will go to apache 1 and everything that starts with /blog could go to some different server. Which would explain why you don't see much in your logs.

Comment: I would bet it is so: the shopping cart has some .asp extension, which clearly is not wordpress. And the blog says wordpress in the page source.

Comment: Well the main thing is its only /blog/ , its all the files & directories inside the folder , but i think so i can take a look at reverse proxies and see if thats what causing this issue .

Comment: Well my issue is fixed , the main issue was reverse proxy which my host fixed .

Comment: Then I was right. And you might accept the answer as correct. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a proxy issue, look for something like that in the httpd.conf:

Reverse Proxy

```
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

Forward Proxy

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from internal.example.com
</Proxy>
```

As you see, there might be an allow from directive in there, that is what you might be running into.

It may also be, that if you are on the main machine, you cannot see the /blog/ sub dir, because your hoster does the proxying for you. Then you would query your machine for a subdirectory it has no knowledge of.

Sadly, no one could tell, unless he could look onto the machine himself. But now that you are armed with all these questions, I am positive you will get nearer to the solution.

Comment: hey kai , really appreciating your help . I did checked out my httpd.conf and no proxies in there , i will ask my hosted server guys about this

Comment: does this thing in httpd.conf  ---<IfModule core.c>
        SSLProxyEngine On
    </IfModule>----------make any diffrence , coz that is in there only for one domain